# Colouring scatter graph by type in r

Tags: r, scatter-plot, scatter

Is there a way you can create a scatter graph in R and colour the points by a category? For example, I have a dataset with a list of x and y points (both columns 'Xpoints' and 'Ypoints' have scales from 0 to 100), but each combined x&y point belongs to one of five categories (in a third column 'Category').
I would like to plot all the combined x&y points AND colour each point by its respective category.
I'm guessing that the five categories would have to allocated numbers 1 to 5 in an additional column. But what would be the code to plot this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ggplot2` package which is widely used for applications such as these.

```
# toy data
my_data <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, replace = T, 100),
                      y = sample(1:100, replace = T, 100),
                      cat = sample(c('first', 'second', 'third'), replace = T, 100)
                      )

# required packages
require(ggplot2)

# make the graph
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = cat)) +
        geom_point()

ggsave(height = 4, width = 4, filename = 'SO36801313.png')
```

The code above provides the following graph.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a really easy task for the graphical package `Lattice`. It is designed especially for multivariate analysis, that can handle really easily.
I load the dataset `iris` to provide an example.

```
library(lattice)
data("iris")
names(iris)
```

`Lattice` allows immediate multifacet plots, showing the relationship between two variables according to a third one. In this case, we examined the relation between the Sepal Length and the Sepal Width of the flower, but for each `species` in the dataset. It is expressed with the formula `x ~ y | z`.

```
xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris)
```

[image]

```
xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris,
   groups = Species, 
   auto.key = TRUE)
```

For your case, we will plot all the observations in a single standard plot. In this case, the argument `groups` will automatically color each observation according to the criteria you choose, in this case, `species` again.

[image]